# Grep {n} The preceding item is matched exactly n times, is not clear to me in case of "Hair", "Haair" and "Haaair"

Tags: grep

Suppose there is three strings "Hair", "Haair" and "Haaair" , When i use grep -E '^Ha{1}' , it returns all the former three words, instead i was expecting only "Hair", as i have asked return a line which starts with H and is followed by letter 'a' exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` does not check that its input matches the given search expression. Grep finds *substrings* of the input that match the search.

See:

```
grep test <<< This is a test.
```

The input does not exactly match `test`. Only *part* of the input matches,

```
This is a test.
```

but that is enough for `grep` to output the whole line.

Similarly, when you say

```
grep -E '^Ha{1}' <<< Haaair
```

The input does not exactly match the search, but a part of it does,

```
Haaair
```

and that is enough. Note that `{n,m}` syntax is purely a convenience: `Ha{1}` is exactly equivalent to `Ha`, `Ha{3,}` is `Haaa+`, `Ha{2,5}` is `Haa(a?){3}` is `Haaa?a?a?`, etc. In other words, `{1}` does not mean "exactly once", it just means "once".

What you want to do is match a `Ha` that is not followed by another `a`. You have two options:

- If your `grep` supports PCRE, you can use a negative lookahead:

  ```
  grep -P '^Ha(?!a)'
  ```

  `(?!a)` is a zero-length assertion, like `^`. It doesn't *match* any characters; it simply causes the match to fail if there is an `a` after the first one.
- Or, you can keep it simple and use a negative `[]`:

  ```
  grep -E '^Ha([^a]|$)'
  ```

  Where `[^a]` matches any single character that is not `a`, and the alternation with `$` handles the case of no character at all.